# Improper integral asymptote shortcut

Tags: improper-integrals

Suppose one has a function
$ \ f(x) = (x-b)^ {-p}  \ $  and ,of course, an asymptote at *x = b* and *p* is positive.

Is it correct that the integral of *f(x)* from *a* to *c*
(where a less than *b* less than *c*) will always converge of the following conditions are met:

*(-p+1)* is greater than 0.
For example *p* could be 2/3 but not 3/2.

(*p* = $\frac{d}{q})$  where *q* is an odd number.

Note that if  *(*p* = $\frac{d}{q})$*  where q is odd then *(1 - p)* must also have an odd denominator.  The resulting function $ \ f(x) = (x-b)^ {-p}  \ $  is therefore defined for all potential upper or lower bounds.

So any integral with an integrand of

$ \ f(x) = (x-b)^ {-p}  \ $  ( where   p = $\frac{d}{q}$  is less than 1 and q is odd) must converge for all possible finite boundaries.

I don't think this is profound in terms of concepts but might help students if pressed for time

(a student can at least rule out convergence just by looking at q).

Examples:

ex.
$\int  _a^b\ f(x) = (x-5)^ { {-2}/{3}}  \ $       will converge for any finite a and b about 5.

ex.
$\int  _a^b\ f(x) = (x-5)^ {{-1}/{2}}  \ $   will not converge for any finite
*a* and *b* about 5.

Comment: Please [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: I tried my best to edit using MathJax.